# Ball freezes at the bottom of the screen and vibrates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Here is my code:

```
if (ball.position.y  < 0 || ball.position.y > size.height) {
    ball_speed.y *= -1;
}
    if (ball.position.x  < 0 || ball.position.x > size.width) {
    ball_speed.x *= -1;
}
```

I am making my game in cocos2d, ball is a sprite and ball_speed is a CGPoint. What happens sometimes the ball freezes at the edge of the screen and just vibrates. Could anyone help me on this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using NSLog to print the position so you can see what's going on while it's vibrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying the logic "if the ball is outside the screen, reverse its velocity along the corresponding axis", which is incorrect: maybe the ball is outside the screen but *already moving the right way*. This happens a lot of your velocity is altered by things other than bounces (such as gravity or friction).

The first part of the solution is to set the direction explicitly:

```
if (ball.position.y < 0) 
  ball_speed.y = fabs(ball_speed.y);

if (ball.position.y > size.height)
  ball_speed.y = - fabs(ball_speed.y);
```

This will ensure that the ball will indeed move back *into* the screen, so there is no possibility of oscillating at the edge.

The second part, which is optional but nonetheless useful if you want correct physics, is to move back the ball into the screen whenever it leaves:

```
if (ball.position.y < 0)
  ball.position.y = 2 * 0 - ball.position.y ;

if (ball.position.y > size.height)
  ball.position.y = 2 * size.height - ball.position.y;
```

Notice the `pos = 2 * limit - pos` which basically mirrors `pos` around `limit`.